# How can I combine 2 associative arrays with different keys and how to get the result array in the input to give order in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, array-merge

I have 2 arrays like:

```
$arr1 =  [230] => Array
        (
            [itemid] => 230
            [name] => test1
            [category] => toy
            [price] => 10.00
        )

    [240] => Array
        (
            [itemid] => 240
            [name] => test2
            [category] => toy
            [price] => 8.00
        )
     [245] => Array
        (
            [itemid] => 245
            [name] => test3
            [category] => pen
            [price] => 5.00
        )
)
$arr2 =  [220] => Array
        (
            [itemid] => 220
            [name] => test4
            [category] => toy
            [price] => 20.00
        )

    [225] => Array
        (
            [itemid] => 225
            [name] => test5
            [category] => battery
            [price] => 4.00
        )
     [248] => Array
        (
            [itemid] => 248
            [name] => test6
            [category] => book
            [price] => 3.00
        )
     [236] => Array
        (
            [itemid] => 236
            [name] => test7
            [category] => pen
            [price] => 2.00
        )
)
```

I need the result like :

```
$arr3 =  [230] => Array
        (
            [itemid] => 230
            [name] => test1
            [category] => toy
            [price] => 10.00
        )

    [240] => Array
        (
            [itemid] => 240
            [name] => test2
            [category] => toy
            [price] => 8.00
        )
     [245] => Array
        (
            [itemid] => 245
            [name] => test3
            [category] => pen
            [price] => 5.00
        )

  [220] => Array
        (
            [itemid] => 220
            [name] => test4
            [category] => toy
            [price] => 20.00
        )

    [225] => Array
        (
            [itemid] => 225
            [name] => test5
            [category] => battery
            [price] => 4.00
        )
     [248] => Array
        (
            [itemid] => 248
            [name] => test6
            [category] => book
            [price] => 3.00
        )
     [236] => Array
        (
            [itemid] => 236
            [name] => test7
            [category] => pen
            [price] => 2.00
        )
)
```

For this I simply using array_merge

```
 $arr3= $arr1+ $arr2;
```

But after that I got the result like:

```
$arr3 =  [230] => Array
        (
            [itemid] => 230
            [name] => test1
            [category] => toy
            [price] => 10.00
        )

    [240] => Array
        (
            [itemid] => 240
            [name] => test2
            [category] => toy
            [price] => 8.00
        )
     

  [220] => Array
        (
            [itemid] => 220
            [name] => test4
            [category] => toy
            [price] => 20.00
        )

    [225] => Array
        (
            [itemid] => 225
            [name] => test5
            [category] => battery
            [price] => 4.00
        )
     [248] => Array
        (
            [itemid] => 248
            [name] => test6
            [category] => book
            [price] => 3.00
        )
       [245] => Array
        (
            [itemid] => 245
            [name] => test3
            [category] => pen
            [price] => 5.00
        )
     [236] => Array
        (
            [itemid] => 236
            [name] => test7
            [category] => pen
            [price] => 2.00
        )
)
```

My issue is after merging 2 associative arrays with different keys, I got the first array and second array mixed which means I need the result like the first three array elements of the first array, after that 4 array elements of the second array.
Can you anyone help me, please, It will be helpful for me

Comment: I'm not really clear on what you're asking. Do you want a sorted array at the end? if so: `asort($arr3);` should do the trick.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: Just loop over `$arr2` and add the keys plus values to `$arr1` seems to achieve what you want? That should maintain the order of the arrays.

Comment: No. I don't want any sorted array. Just I want to array as given in input array order.

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
foreach($arr2 as $key => $record) {
    $arr1[$key] = $record;
}
```

This would result in the order you're looking for.

[demo](https://3v4l.org/LYCUO)